# Click div on Selenium doesnt fire the event. What else can I try?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-ide

So I am testing with selenium,  and there is an onClick event on a div.

I verified it on Selenium IDE and got an event on a specific xPath.

Then I use that xPath on my code, got the element, and perform a click,  but the event is not fired.

What else can I try to fire that event?

Thanks

I am running selenium version 2.44.0,  on Firefox, using C#.

This is my code:

```
IWebElement div = webdriver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[@data-planparticular='1']"));
div.Click();
```

Comment: Which Browser (and version) are you trying?

Comment: I am running selenium version 2.44.0, on Firefox, using C#.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I ended up trying the click on many different places and found one that it works fine.

For example, if I have:

```
<div><div><div><p></p></div></div></div>
```

I tried first clicking on the `<p>` element
Then on each `<div>` until one worked, even if that particular div didn't have the event wired to it.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you use javascript for it? like

```
 IWebDriver driver;    
    IJavaScriptExecutor js = driver as IJavaScriptExecutor;       
    string title = (string)js.ExecuteScript("element.click()");
```